# Expanding EM field of a charged particle

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electric-fields, charge

Every electron and proton in the universe came into existence at some point of time - whether at the big bang, or a long time afterwards through processes such as pair production. Would it be accurate to say that at the moment a charged particle comes into existence, its electromagnetic field propagates outwards at the speed of light? So for example in an inertial rest frame would the electric field actually be $$E = \frac{k_eq}{r^2} H(ct-r)$$ where $H$ is the heaviside function? And furthermore, would this not be a solution to the age old problem of the total energy of the coulomb field being infinite, since the fields do not actually permeate throughout an infinite space?

Comment: Note that the continuity equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho + \nabla \cdot \mathbf J = 0$ is implied by the Maxwell equations; violating it by bringing a single charge into existence at a point means that your question presupposes that the Maxwell equations are not valid.

Comment: I am not talking about only bringing one charge into existence as that would break charge / mass conservation beyond simply the continuity equation. I am saying to focus on one charge and ignore any other particles created or destroyed at the same time.

Comment: But that's the problem - if e.g. an electron and positron come into existence at the same point, their fields precisely cancel; as they move apart, we start to observe a dipole field.  You'll never observe a *radial* field propagating outward in the manner you describe, because the corresponding electromagnetic disturbance would have to be longitudinally polarized.

Comment: My question is fundamentally about if it's accurate to think of the fields as expanding once the particles comes into existence. As mentioned, my coulomb example is just about the field due only to that particle in its rest frame. My question would still apply if an electron and positron come into existence and form a dipole - would the dipole field grow outwards at speed c?

Answer (score 2):

> Would this not be a solution to the age old problem of the total energy of the coulomb field being infinite, since the fields do not actually permeate throughout an infinite space?

No, because the infinite space isn't the problem.  If we try to integrate the field energy of a static charge over all space, we have
$$
E = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \iiint E^2 \, dV = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \left( \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \right)^2 \iiint \frac{1}{r^4} r^2 \sin \theta \, dr \, d \theta \, d \phi \\
= \frac{q^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_0^\infty \frac{dr}{r^2} 
$$
If we split this last integral up into two pieces relative to some radius $R > 0$, we get
$$
E = \frac{q^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_0} \left[ \int_0^R \frac{dr}{r^2} + \int_R^\infty \frac{dr}{r^2} \right]
$$
The second integral is finite, no matter what $R$ is (it's equal to $1/R$);  and the first integral is infinite, no matter what $R$ is.  This means that the divergence of the total field energy is not due to the field's infinite volume, but rather due to its infinite density near the point charge.