# Electric field of an electron after it comes into existence

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge, conservation-laws, causality

This is a followup of an older post I made [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/621609/), whose main premise was not answered. Suppose than an electron is created in a scattering experiment, where other particles are created/destroyed in accordance with conservation laws. If we think about only the electric (or magnetic) field due to to electron, and not the total field, would it be accurate to say that it must be in the form

$$\vec{E} = \vec{f}(x,y,z,t)H(ct-r)$$

where $H$ is the Heaviside step function? And if for example the electron is non-accelerating after creation, would f just be the usual Coulomb field of a point particle?

Comment: Such field violates Maxwell's equations, in particular, local conservation of charge. Particle creation has to obey conservation of charge, and EM field has to mirror that.

Comment: @Denn after a question has received answers it is against the policy to edit the question in a way that makes the existing answers incorrect or incomplete. Please ask a new question instead. Sorry I was not clearer about what I meant when I said “those are completely different questions”. I meant for you to ask a new question, not edit this one. I have reverted the edits here

Answer (score 2):

Since we observe charge conservation, we conclude that if an electron appears, either a negatively charged particle must disappear or a positively charged particle must also appear. In either case, the field due to the combination doesn't change until the new particles move away from the interaction point. A step function is not a sensible model.

Answer (score 1):

> If we think about only the electric (or magnetic) field due to to electron, and not the total field, would it be accurate to say that it must be in the form
>
> $\vec{E} = \vec{f}(x,y,z,t)H(ct-r)$
>
> where H is the Heaviside step function?

Not really. Maxwell’s equations only govern the total E field. You can certainly split it into parts from each charge, if you wish. But that split is arbitrary and non-physical. So you have lots of flexibility in how you would do so.

For example, you could assign fields to particles using the Coulomb gauge. This would change the field instantaneously everywhere to belong to the new electron instead of the parent particle.

There is no reason that the fraction of the total field that you label as the field due to the electron needs to expand at c.

Comment: I guess the idea I'm trying to gauge isn't whether the field expands at c precisely, but that it expands at a rate that is capped by c. If say an electron and positron were created at the same point, my question could be modified by asking if the total field due to both particles expands no faster than the speed of light.

Comment: @Denn those are completely different questions. A question about the total field is a physical question with a physical answer. A question about an arbitrary division of the total field is inherently arbitrary. The arbitrary division can expand at any rate. The total field cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to describe this situation consistently by mixing the creation/destruction of an electron with a classical field generated by the same electron. Classical radiation fields are macroscopic coherent superpositions of photons. A situation not highly probable with just one electron.

Comment: Classical electrostatics is perfectly observable with single electrons, cf. the Millikan oil-drop experiment.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, true. but with effects only at a macroscopic scale (the oil drop). Moreover, in that case the electron does not appear suddenly.